# Spring @ResponseBody: format JSON to put status

Tags: android, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to map some pojos as `JSON` with jackson technology using spring to create a web service, but I have a problem, when I map a list as `JSON` it creates a malformed `JSON` like:

```
["idLine":"a61dcedb-4a6b-4f8f-bbdd-32cc51e861b2",
     "name":"line1",
     "code":"pru1"
]
```

I want to create a `mapper`, a `filter` or something similar to get a response like:

```
{
 status:"OK",
 data:[
    {"idLine":"a61dcedb-4a6b-4f8f-bbdd-32cc51e861b2",
     "name":"line1",
     "code":"pru1"
    }]
}
```

I have tryed something with `ObjectMapper` but with no result.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
This line is the one that parses and invokes a malformed exception (it belongs to a external library)

```
result = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(str).nextValue();
```

And the JSON that I'm trying to parse is:

```
[{"idLine":"a61dcedb-4a6b-4f8f-bbdd-32cc51e861b2","name":"linea1","code":"pru1","colour":"#ff3200","means":"Bus","type":"urban","notes":"","state":true,"timetableInterurbans":[]}]
```

To clarify, I serialize a Pojo on Spring using @ResponseBody and then the response is retrieved by android and parsed using JSONObject which throws an exception.

The server side method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{country}/{cityName}/{type}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Line> getUrbanLinesFromCity(@PathVariable String country, @PathVariable String cityName, @PathVariable String type){
    //Get the city pojo by country and city name
    City city = cityManager.searchCityByCountryAndName(country, cityName);
    //Get the lines from the city
    List<Line> lines = null;
    if (city != null){
        lines = lineManager.getLinesByCityAndType(city.getIdCity(), type);
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: What is the structure of the object you are trying to serialize that produces the malformed json?  Specifically, what are the elements of the list?

Comment: Ok, I'll modify my post to show the entry that produces an error when it is parsed by JSON

Comment: I have updated the code as mentioned

Comment: This question makes no sense. Are you trying to serialize or deserialize? Also, you mention Jackson but your code shows use of JSON.org. You might want to spend some time and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. I will clarify the question but to start with: I serialize it on a web service and get it on an android device using a library. Only serialize

Comment: Ok your question makes more sense now. You are serializing a POJO on the server side (web service) using Spring/Jackson, then deserializing in the client Android app using JSON.org. The only thing you need to include now is your server side service showing the method being invoked.

Comment: Ok I added the server side, of course, it is on a controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved it by using a helper class called `JSONResponse`. It has two attributes, one that means the status of the request and other that means the data response.

```
public class JSONResponse{
    private Object data;
    private boolean status;

    public JSONResponse (Object data){
        this.data = data;
        this.status = this.data != null;
    }

    //getters and setters for both attributes to be serialized
}
```

Now the only thing I have to do is serialize this helper object with the data inside, getting a consistent JSON Response over multiple API calls using `@RequestBody JSONResponse` as the returning value for each method in every controller.